# Syntax error while defining new HashMap<>(); or new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java, arraylist

I have imported some project into my workspace. it has some hashmaps, arraylist etc. it has syntax error in this `<>` part of code.

for example definition of array list is `ArrayList<String> bases = null;` but when a make a new instance like `bases = Arraylist<>();` it gets a syntax error.

I have jre1.7 and JDK 7 installed on my system

Comment: If you are using generics, shouldn't you specify the type argument... `= Arraylist<string>();`

Comment: Do you have the word "new" after the "=" sign or not?  It's in your question title but not your question body.

Comment: @DavidWallace it has new after =
i just forgot to write that in question. i guess its something with my eclipse preferences ! because this project works with another systems or another eclipse!

Comment: @DavidWallace this is also one of the exceptions :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from DefaultComboBoxModel<?> to DefaultComboBoxModel<String>
 Cannot instantiate the type DefaultComboBoxModel<?>
 Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token

Answer (score 2):

`bases = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a declaration for a generic type, but it's missing the letter. Try filling in the brackets with a letter and declaring the letter as a generic type in the class header.

Answer (score 0):

This (`<>`) is called diamond operator (type inference), it is added to Java in 1.7. Having Java 7 installed on your system is not enough, your project should also be using Java, so make it use Java 7 from your ide's project settings.

Comment: you mean in java build path? i've change it to java 7 from that project properties but the problem is still on !

Answer (score 0):

diamond is only support by jdk7 (and later version). You have jdk7 installed on your **system**. You should make sure your IDE (eclipse?) uses the jdk/jre7 for your project.

also it maybe a typo in your question. you need the `new` keyword and `ArrayList` (big L).

```
xxx = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: i don't have any other JDK or JRE even installed on my computer right now!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use raw types, then declare and assign like following:

```
ArrayList bases = null;
bases = new ArrayList();
```

If you are using generics and JDK7, then declare the TYPE of the object to be stored, and use the diamond operator:

```
ArrayList<TYPE> bases = null;
bases = new ArrayList<>();
```

More info: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/2619091)